# Django not displaying query in template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I am trying to display filtered objects in my django template however for some reason I don't know django does not display them.

I have a similar views function and template which does indeed display but this particular function does not.

Here are my urls.py, html template and views.py files:

The views.py function responsible for the url:

```
def game_category_list(request, slug):
    template = 'game_category_list.html'
    category = get_object_or_404(gameIdentifier, game_choice=slug)
    post = gameIdentifier.objects.filter(game_choice=category)

    context = {
        'category':category,
        'post':post,
    }

    return render(request, template, context)
```

Url.py (which contains another url called  and this does display all the posts associated with the slug.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('categories/<slug:slug>', views.game_category_list, name='game_category_list'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.category_detail, name='game_category'),

]
```

Here is the html file for the game_category_list function:

```
{% extends 'base_layout.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class='gamecategories'>
    {% for game in post %}
    <div class='gamecategoriesdisplay'>
        <h1>{{game.game_name}}</h1>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

I don't know why this doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you any gameIdentifier records in your database? Did you check it?

Comment: yes I have multiple. I even used the filter in the manage.py shell and got a query return in there. It doesn't work in the template though.

Comment: Ok, can you print result of `gameIdentifier.objects.filter(game_choice=category)`?

Comment: I used '2D' as category and get 'Brawlhalla' which is the only game I listed under 2D.

Comment: <QuerySet [<gameIdentifier: Brawlhalla>]>, this is what I get. I can also loop through this in shell and get game_name and other model fields too

Comment: Did you have block named content in your base_layout.html?

Comment: Yeah. As I said my other query displays correctly in the same block and base_layout.

Comment: Ok I have found the error to the problem. I tried printing the 'post' and 'slug' variables and in the console it returns an empty queryset.

Comment: Try running it without `game_choice=category` and record the results. If it lists all the games then your problem is at `category = get_object_or_404(gameIdentifier, game_choice=slug)`. Since we don't have full access to your code we can't diagnose the problems there propperly.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. it was due to filter not matching capital letters from my categories, you have to make sure your categories are added in lowecase so it match with the slugs in the url. Once you have changed it, you have to reassign the category or it will keep showing the older one